# Get a List from a Map?

Tags: java

How can I get a HashMap to a List? Something like:

```
Map<String, Horse> horses = new HashMap<String, Horse>();

ArrayList<Horse> = horses.toArray();
```

?

Thanks

Comment: To be clear, you want only the values and not the keys, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Horse> horsesAsList = new ArrayList<Horse>(horses.values());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Horses> = new ArrayList<Horses>(horses.values());
```

`horses.values()` returns a `Collection`, if that is also fine you can skip the creation of the `ArrayList`.